# How to exporting dataframe to excel sheet with grouping based in categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe with about 60K lines, with the structure similar to the one below:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| a | 5 | 6 |
| a | 3 | 0 |
| b | 3 | 12 |
| b | 4 | 21 |
| c | 7 | 31 |

In Col1 column, I have cartegories of varying size and each time the database is updated the number of rows also changes.

It is possible to export the dataframe in xlsx format with already formatted lines (similar to what occurs https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_outlines.html) but that the categories are detected automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible. Here is one way to achieve what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'Col2': [1, 5, 3, 3, 4, 7],
                   'Col3': [2, 6, 0, 12, 21, 31]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define a format for the first category in the group
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Iterate through the dataframe. If row is the first record of the group apply format and the collapsed '+' symbol,
# for the rest records of the group assign them in the same level and hide them
for row in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[row, 0] != df.iloc[row-1, 0]:
        cell_format = bold
        outline_option = {'collapsed': True}
    else:
        cell_format = None
        outline_option = {'level': 1, 'hidden': True}

    worksheet.set_row(row+1, None, cell_format, outline_option)

writer.save()
```

File is saved like this:

[image]

And if you expand the rows you will get:
[image]

If the output is not exactly what you want, you can tweak the code to suit your needs. But i hope you got the idea.